# Codeigniter Error Message: You must enable php_gmp to use Bitauth

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-gmp

I keep getting an error message on my linux and windows message which states that I am to ***enable php_gmp*** in order to use Bitauth. I have placed **extension=php_gmp.so** in the *php.ini* folder in the **opt/lampp/etc** folder and also in ***etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini*** folder also on my linux but to no avail. Please how do I enable php_gmp on linux and windows? I am working with codeigniter

Comment: Did you restart apache ?

Comment: Yes I did but same result

Comment: Run this command as a root user sudo apt-get install php-gmp and restart apache

Comment: Just did it, same result.

Comment: Any ideas on how to rectify the issue on windows cause both OS give me same error message

Answer (score 1):

For windows, gmp is most likely already installed. just go to your php.ini file and uncomment the line **extension=php_gmp.dll**
from

> ;extension=php_gmp.dll

to

> extension=php_gmp.dll

then restart the apache service. Checked this in PHP 5.3.8 and it solves the problem